# Flare artboard items taking time to render on Flare character

Tags: animation, dart, flutter, flare

I have a Flare character on that I have to display some items by their node when I am updating the node and the item is displaying on character, it is taking some time and getting delayed, in my `ChimpCharacter` class whenever I choose the item by a tap on the item, the whole class is updating and its initState is calling again, I am using `ScopedModel` for updating state.

Here is the link to my flare character that I am using

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14hI_cezteapxiF8xDT6w-DrcIwPIhb8n/view?usp=sharing

My `main.dart`

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Item item1 = Item('brac1');
    Item item2 = Item('glasses1');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ScopedModel<AppModel>(
        model: AppModel(),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: ScopedModelDescendant<AppModel>(
                      builder: (context, child, model) {
                    return ChimpCharacter(
                      itemNames: model.items,
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: ScopedModelDescendant<AppModel>(
                    builder: (context, child, model) {
                      return Wrap(
                        spacing: 100.0,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            elevation: 3.0,
                            onPressed: () {
                              model.addItem(item1);
                              print('model is ${model.items}');
                            },
                            child: Text('Braclet'),
                          ),
                          RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            elevation: 3.0,
                            onPressed: () {
                              model.addItem(item2);
                              print('model is ${model.items}');
                            },
                            child: Text('Glasses'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My `model.dart`

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class AppModel extends Model {
  List<Item> _items = [];
  List<Item> get items => _items;

  void addItem(Item item) {
    this._items = items;
    if (_items.contains(item)) {
      _items.remove(item);
    } else {
      _items.add(item);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Item {
  String itemName;
  Item(this.itemName);
}
```

my chimpcharacter.dart

```
class ChimpCharacter extends StatefulWidget {
  ChimpCharacter({Key key, this.itemNames}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Item> itemNames;

  @override
  _ChimpCharacterState createState() => _ChimpCharacterState();
}

class _ChimpCharacterState extends State<ChimpCharacter>
    implements FlareController {
  List<String> items = [];
  FlareController flareController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState called ');
    if (widget.itemNames != null) {
      widget.itemNames.map((s) {
        items.add(s.itemName);
      }).toList(growable: false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlareActor(
      'assets/chimp.flr',
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      animation: 'walking',
      controller: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool advance(FlutterActorArtboard artboard, double elapsed) {
    // print('advance');
    if (items != null) {
      items.forEach((String item) {
        final ActorNode acceName = artboard.getNode(item);
        acceName.collapsedVisibility = false;
      });
    }

    return false;
  }

  @override
  void initialize(FlutterActorArtboard artboard) {}

  @override
  void setViewTransform(Mat2D viewTransform) {
    print('setViewTransform');
  }

  @override
  ValueNotifier<bool> isActive;
}
```